# Push elements to BehavioSubject of array. Typescript Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, behaviorsubject

I have a Subject of array type and I have 2 components that update the data of the subject and one component that subscribe to it. The think is that when any I update the subject from any of the 2 components, the array is overwritten. I need to be able to push data to the subject from both of this two components and have a combined array with the two sources info.

I tried this:

```
 actualizarArchivos(archivos:IArchivo[]){
    this.archivos.next([...this.archivos.getValue(), ...archivos]);
  }
```

but when I push 3 elements they got duplicatedand I get an array of 6 elements. Anyone knows if there is a way to accomplish this?

Comment: pass only new archive to the method and change method body to `this.archivos.next([...this.archivos.getValue(), archive]);`

Comment: It looks fine to me. Can you explain what you are expecting with some examples?

Answer (score 0):

As @Andrei's Comment suggest. Passing only new archive to the method like this:

```
this.archivos.next([...this.archivos.getValue(), archive]);
```

solve the problem.